# Javascript/HTML - Inserting audio from object

Tags: javascript, html

I have an object here in a file called audio.js:

```
const audio = {
  controls: true,
  source: [
    {
      src: 'https://testname.com/Track03.mp3',
      type: 'audio/mpeg'
    },
    {
      src: 'https://testname.com/Track03.ogg',
      type: 'audio/ogg'
    }
  ]
};
```

I've included the audio.js file, but am completely lost on how to render these two audio players into my website, using a loop probably. 
All I've managed to get done so far is this, which is evidently incomplete, and would like to expand on it if possible.

```
<div id="audio">
  <script>
  let audioo = document.createElement('audio');
  </script>
</div>
```

Sorry, I'm new to all of this and can't find any reliable information. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way you can generate them dynamically by javascript; and you don't need to put this string inside `<div id='audio'></div>` to work, you can use it any where in your javascript.

```js
const audio = {
  controls: true,
  source: [
    {
      src: 'https://testname.com/Track03.mp3',
      type: 'audio/mpeg'
    },
    {
      src: 'https://testname.com/Track03.ogg',
      type: 'audio/ogg'
    }
  ]
}
const theDiv = document.querySelector("#audio");
audio.source.forEach(as=>{
  let newAudioElement = document.createElement('audio');
  newAudioElement.src = as.src;
  newAudioElement.type = as.type;
  newAudioElement.controls = 'controls';
  theDiv.appendChild(newAudioElement);
})
```

---

Here is a working example:

```js
// replacing some working audio urls
const audio = {
  controls: true,
  source: [
    {
      src: 'https://www.w3schools.com/tags/horse.mp3',
      type: 'audio/mp3'
    },
    {
      src: 'https://www.w3schools.com/tags/horse.ogg',
      type: 'audio/ogg'
    }
  ]
}
const theDiv = document.querySelector("#audio");

audio.source.forEach(as=>{
  let newAudioElement = document.createElement('audio');
  newAudioElement.src = as.src;
  newAudioElement.type = as.type;
  newAudioElement.controls = 'controls';
  theDiv.appendChild(newAudioElement);
})
```

```html
<div id="audio"></div>
```